# Including a post title in a twitter link

Tags: twitter, get-the-title

Im trying to make a Twitter button on each article of my blog. This is the code I use on single.php

```
<a href="http://twitter.com/home?status=<?php echo urlencode(get_the_title()); ?>">
Tweet this!
</a>
```

The problem is that I have a blog post with this title:

> Give format to “bodytext”

and when I tweet it, the quotes appear as

> Give format to &#8220;bodytext&#8221;

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `get_the_title()` will pass the title through a filter that texturizes the quotes.  So a regular " becomes a curly quote (“) and `urlencode()` will break it.

So instead, write your own title function and use that:

```
function my_get_the_title() {
    global $post;

    return $post->post_title;
}
```

This should bypass any unwanted filters and let you work with regular quotes.

Comment: That doesnt work. Is there a typo in the code? I added it in functions.php

Comment: Ok, found. Its not post->title. Its post->post_title. Thanks!